# Magento Community 1.9.1 RWD theme, how do I fix FeatureZoom over sized product image?

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, rwd-theme

I'm trying to setup product image zoom using [FeatureZoom](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/vs-product-image-zoom-featurezoom.html)... but the product image is way too big and the CSS seems to be all in-line. Please help me make the image smaller? 
tia
http://kaleidoscopiacoloringbooks.com/Store/mandala1.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.product-image-gallery .gallery-image.visible {
     width: 200px;
}
```

Is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: yes thank you! I struggle with how to find relevant CSS in the Developer tools (chrome).